# What is the difference between reciprocating and oscillating motion? How is reciprocating motion different from simple harmonic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

I wanted a good explanation for the difference between [reciprocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocating_motion) and sinusoidal motion (For e.g. SHM). This question has been posted here due to many ambiguous and unclear explanations round the Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a motion to be called simple harmonic, the force should be proportional and opposite to the displacement: $F = -kx$. Reciprocating motion is just a back-and-forth motion and per se, does not have to follow said law.

Comment: Well, in the last paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocating_motion , There is a practical difference. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Uniform circular motion and simple harmonic motion are very closely related: the projection of a particle exhibiting $\textbf{uniform}$ circular motion performs a simple harmonic motion.

https://byjus.com/physics/simple-harmonic-motion-and-uniform-circular-motion/

That is what is said about the motion of the rotating part. The part of the connecting rod connected to the piston, however, does not exhibit a simple harmonic motion, because the angle of the rod changes continuously.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot. :)